# Syntax Error in insert upto? MSAccess

Tags: java, sql, ms-access-2010

I am trying to insert data a user enters into a jtextfield into an msaccess database. When I try to execute my sql statement I get an error stating Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
I checked my sql statement and tried a few different things but cannot seem to find any kind of syntax error.

```
    conn = Connect.ConnectDB();
    String sql = "insert into Team ("
            +"TeamID,"
            +"TeamCity,"
            +"TeamMascot,"
            + "values("+txtid.getText()+ ",'"+txtname.getText()+"','"+txtaddress.getText()+"')" ;
    try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entry " + txtid.getText() + " Saved");
        UpdateJTable();
        //conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is the **extra comma and no closing parenthesis before the keyword `values`**

```
String sql = "insert into Team ("
            +"TeamID,"
            +"TeamCity,"
            +"TeamMascot,"    // <<== HERE, change comma into closing parenthesis
```

By the way, your statement is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. You can avoid it if you parameterized the values. Eg,

```
String sql = "insert into Team (TeamID,TeamCity,TeamMascot) values (?, ?, ?, ?)"
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, txtid.getText());
pst.setString(2, txtname.getText());
pst.setString(3, txtaddress.getText());
```

- [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: Thanks a ton for the clear answer and more! This is just for a small school project so I am not too worried about SQL Injection but I will be sure to put my values in the parameter in the future.